# how to put a button at the end of ExpandableListview dynamically in android

Tags: android, expandablelistview

In my application i have an activity which extends ExpandableListActivity, there i want to put a button at the end of ExpandableListview, so that if i exapand it should be at the end of listview.

The problem is after exapanding all the items in Expandablelistview it takes the full screen and the button does not appear.
How can I scroll button with ExpandableListview?
I also tried to give Scrollview but its not working.
Give me a way what should I write in xml file for proper o/p.
Thank you

Answer (score -1):

Create a `footerview layout` consisting of `Button` that you want to set as footer and then try

```
View footerView = ((LayoutInflater)ActivityContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.footer_layout, null, false);
ListView.addFooterView(footerView);
```

Footer_layout xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="7dip"
    android:paddingBottom="7dip"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center">
    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/footer_layout" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

    <Button          
        android:id="@+id/footer_1" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip">
    </Button> 

</LinearLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: footer_layout.xml is contains what? only that Listview or also along with button?